# Alignment of column headers in siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx

I have the following table:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[locale = DE, round-mode = places, round-precision =
4]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lS*6{S[table-format=-1.8]}}
\toprule
& {Reference} & {FML} & {IFM} & {IFM (NV)} & {PML} & {MM} \\
\midrule
{MSE} & 0.05924657 & 0.07423921 & 0.08774748 & 0.18118911 & 0.13403073
                                                                 & 0.16849250 \\
{Bias} & 0.01030783 & 0.01524758 & -0.06442111 & -0.18893351 & -0.02010527 & 0.03427978 \\
{Std.dev.}  & 0.2433095 & 0.2721779 & 0.2892768 & 0.3816266  & 0.3657325 & 0.40924921 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{My table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

However, the alignment of the column headers is off. I'd like them centred over the column content. I've tried various options such as `table-alignment` to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`table-format=-1.8` reserves place for eight decimal digits after the decimal marker, but only four are actually used. Also not all columns contain negative numbers.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
  locale = DE,
  round-mode = places,
  round-precision = 4]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
  l
  *2{S[table-format=1.4]}
  *3{S[table-format=-1.4]}
  S[table-format=1.4]
}
\toprule
& {Reference} & {FML} & {IFM} & {IFM (NV)} & {PML} & {MM} \\
\midrule
{MSE} & 0.05924657 & 0.07423921 & 0.08774748 & 0.18118911 & 0.13403073 & 0.16849250 \\
{Bias} & 0.01030783 & 0.01524758 & -0.06442111 & -0.18893351 & -0.02010527 & 0.03427978 \\
{Std.dev.} & 0.2433095 & 0.2721779 & 0.2892768 & 0.3816266  & 0.3657325 & 0.40924921 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{My table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

With vertical rules to make it easier to see the centering of the header row cells:

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% no extra space around columns
\begin{tabular}{
  l|
  *2{S[table-format=1.4]|}
  *3{S[table-format=-1.4]|}
  S[table-format=1.4]|
}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: While the Reference, FML, MM and IFM (NV) columns seem to be properly centred, it seems like the PML and IFM columns aren't.

Comment: @user2249626 An optical illusion, because the minus sign is quite large and is not present at the first data row, see the updated answer.